# What does $r_*$ represent in Poisson's formula for the Laplace equation on a disk?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am currently taking a course in partial differential equations, we have recently covered solving the Laplace equation on a disk. We derived Poisson's formula: $$U(r, \theta) = \frac{r_*^2-r^2}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(\theta')}{r_*^2-2rr_* cos(\theta-\theta') + r^2} d\theta' $$
I am confused as to what the physical interpreation of $r_*$ is, can anyone explain this?

Comment: What is the radius of your disk?

Comment: The radius is given by $r$, isn't it?

Comment: Wrong. That is the running variable, see, $U$ depends on $r$.

Comment: So $r_*$ is the radius then? What does $r$ represent then?

Comment: In this notation, $U$ if the harmonic function in $B_{r_\ast}$ with boundary data $f$. Then $(r,\theta)$ denotes a point in $B_{r_\ast}$ written in polar coordinates